# How to fit picture and text inside a flowlayoutpanel with a dynamically created radiobutton in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a program that displays a candidate running in a position. Example President. I made a all my controls dynamic. I created a `FlowLayoutPanel` and inside is a `RadioButton` which has a `.Text` of the candidate.

My code :

```
    private void FPreview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelPresident();
    }

    FlowLayoutPanel PresPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();

    private void PanelPresident()
    {
        Label PresLabel = new Label();
        PresLabel.Text = "PRESIDENT";
        PresLabel.AutoSize = true;
        PresLabel.Location = new Point(50, 210);
        PresLabel.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        PresLabel.Font = new Font("Courier New", 15);
        PresLabel.ForeColor = Color.Aquamarine;
        this.Controls.Add(PresLabel);

        PresPanel.Size = new Size(160, 300);
        PresPanel.Location = new Point(30, 240);
        PresPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        PresPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        PresPanel.AutoScroll = true;
        PresPanel.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
        PresPanel.WrapContents = false;
        Controls.Add(PresPanel);

        PresPanel.SuspendLayout();

        try
        {
            string cmdPres = "SELECT (LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName) as PresName, " +
                        "imgPath as PresImagePath, " + "id as PresID FROM TableVote WHERE Position='President'";
            using (SqlCommand Prescom = new SqlCommand(cmdPres, sc))
            {
                if (sc.State != ConnectionState.Open) sc.Open();
                SqlDataReader Presreader = Prescom.ExecuteReader();
                while (Presreader.Read())
                {
                    PresRadioButton(Presreader.GetString(0), Presreader.GetString(1), Presreader.GetInt32(2));
                }
                Presreader.Close();
                sc.Close();
                PresPanel.ResumeLayout(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void PresRadioButton(string PresName, string PresimagePath, int PresID)
    {
        RadioButton Presradio = new RadioButton { Text = PresName, Parent = PresPanel };
        Presradio.AutoSize = false;
        Presradio.Size = new Size(130, 130);
        Presradio.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(PresimagePath), 90, 90);
        Presradio.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText;
        Presradio.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        Presradio.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        Presradio.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        Presradio.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;

        Presradio.Tag = PresID;
    }
```

My Problem is, if the Text of radiobutton is long, the picture wont fit. it does not show the full picture. Can you help me fix this problem by fitting my picture inside the `flowlayoutpanel` even though the text is long. Thanks :)

Comment: looking at your code, I don't think you have such a problem, I can see you set the `Size` of your `Presradio` to `130,130`, while the `Size` of your `Image` is just `90,90`. That means the `Image` should always be displayed in the `Presradio`, of course however your problem might be the `Text` could not be fully displayed in your `Presradio` if it's long enough.

Comment: @KingKing yes that's my problem.. coz i am about to finish my Automated Voting system. But that's just the problem im looking forward to have a solution. because when the text is long, the picture wont be in normal size..

Comment: I don't understand why you always complain about the `Picture size`? As I said, you hardcodedly set its size to `90,90`, it won't never be larger or smaller.

Comment: I have an idea. I think i can set the max length of the `textboxes`

Comment: of my `FirstName, MiddleName and LastName`, so the picture wont go small..